# pdflatex missing T2A fonts?

Tags: latex, pdflatex, tex-live

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T2A/lmr/m/n' undefined
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T2A/lmr/bx/n' undefined
```

Where can I get them?

pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022)

Example code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,onecolumn,twoside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{cmap}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[czech,english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{czech}

\begin{description}

\item [KID] \foreignlanguage{russian}{Клапан Избыточного Давления}

\item [PK] \foreignlanguage{russian}{Рабочая Кассета}

\item [\foreignlanguage{russian}{твэл}]
  \foreignlanguage{russian}{тепловыделяющий элемент}

\item [\foreignlanguage{russian}{твэг}]
  \foreignlanguage{russian}{тепловыделяющий элемент с уран-гадолиниевым топливом}
  
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

Some text added to make the editor happy

Comment: It usually works the other way round, you don't get the missing shapes, instead you choose a font which has them. Can you make a [mre]?

Comment: Try without `\usepackage{lmodern}`. I can't read the text, so no idea if it is shown correctly, but it looks bold https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvIvw.png

Comment: (and don't load the same package with different options, instead use `\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}` to load them in one go)

Comment: OK, it works without it. Thank you, I used lmodern for long time because it made the document nicer. Maybe, it is no longer the case.

Comment: You could have a look at other fonts with T2A support, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/114598/36296 . However IMHO, there isn't a very big difference between computer modern and latin modern in "normal" sized documents, like an article. The main advantage of latin modern is scaleability, which becomes important if fonts are used at unusual big or small sizes, e.g. on posters, but that's not that big of a problem in articles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `lmodern` package does not have these fonts shapes, you will need another font which does has them.

The easiest solution would be to remove `lmodern` package and use the default computer modern font instead.

Alternatively you could look into other fonts which support T2A, e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/114598/36296 or you could use lualatex or xelatex instead of pdflatex, which will give you more options to choose a fonts because they make all the fonts installed on your computer available to use in your document.